# Is it possible to implement webhooks on regular clients?

Tags: python, sockets, real-time, long-polling, webhooks

I am trying to create a python application that can continuously receive data from a webserver. This python application will be running on multiple personal computers, and whenever new data is available it will receive it. I realize that I can do this either by long polling or web sockets, but the problem is that sometimes data won't be transferred for days and in that case long polling or websockets seem to be inefficient. I won't be needing that long of a connection but whenever data is available I need to be able to push it to the application. I have been reading about webhooks and it seems that if I can have a url to post that data to, I won't need to poll. But I am confused as to how each client would have a callback url because in that case a client would have to act as a server. Are there any libraries that help in getting this done? Any kind of resources that you can point me to would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

backchoi32,

What you want to do is read up on [REST architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Essentially, your clients are going to perform a POST request to a specific resource, let's call the resource `clients`. What your clients can then do, is perform a GET request to "/:cliend_id" and when that occurs, your back end can then go on to persist this information in your database.

There are many RESTful web frameworks out there in python, a couple popular ones are [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

This article from Python Diary called, "[Creating a simple CRUD application](http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/simple-crud-app-django.html)" and this slide shared called "[Basic CRUD in Django](http://www.slideshare.net/mcantelon/basic-crud-in-django)" will teach you what you need to know about writing a RESTful web service which has basic (C)reate (R)ead (U)pdate (D)elete functionality.

All you need to worry about on your client side, is to ensure that you are receiving a 200 [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) back, which will signal to your client that it successfully performed the request to your back-end service and that if you performed a POST/PUT everything was persisted. If it doesn't return a 200, then you can then add functionality to deal with failures, redundancies and fault-tolerance.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then how is this different from long polling? Because I would still have the client to goto "/:cliend_id/results" periodically in order to check whether the data is available, right? Also I would want the backend to post data to the url which can be then received by the client.

Comment: Hey @bachkoi32, great question! In long polling, if the server does not have any information available for the client when the poll is received, instead of sending an empty response, the server holds the request open and waits for response information to become available. In what i'm suggesting, you can simply set your clients to periodically check their resources on the server (this could be every hour, every 6 hours, every day) and that's it. If it's available then it's sent to your client, if it's not, then you wait for the next client request.

Comment: You are essentially building a pub/sub service but in this case the expense of keeping the socket open isn't worth it since nothing really has to be done in real time. Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send data to the client without having some kind of connection, e.g. either websockets or (long) polling done by the client. While it would be possible in theory to open a listener socket on the client and let the web server could connect to and sent the data to this socket, this will not work in reality. The main reason for thi is, that the client is often inside an internal network not reachable from outside, i.e. a typical home setup with multiple computers behind a single IP or a corporate setup with a firewall in between. In this case it is only possible to establish a connection from inside to outside, but not the other way.